# Application for my downloads

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-one

I am a beginner with xbox one I recently received and I was wondering does anyone know if there's any way I can check my downloads and installations when out and about?

Comment: When you say out and about, you mean away from your Xbox?  I don't think you can while away from your Xbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Xbox app for your phone.  Log into XBox Live, make sure you're on the same Wi-Fi connection, start your download.  It'll show your progress through the app.

Comment: That's how you set it up on the first install.  When you walk away from said wi-fi, it SHOULD show you the progress on the app

Answer (score -1):

The answer is preatty easy:

Home -> My games & Apps -> Queue

Active downloads are shown with a progress bar and installations are shown with a notification.

Source: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/store/view-status-software-install